# Hadoop Streaming, C#, & Azure with External Libraries

Tags: c#, azure, hadoop

I'm using Hadoop Streaming to run a mapreduce job in C# on a Linux cluster in Azure. However, I need to use the MathNet.Numerics library. I grabbed the dll using the NuGet package manager then included the dll as a reference file and in a lib folder as well as ensured that the build action is set to: Embedded Resource.

Whenever I try to run the following command:

```
hadoop jar ./hadoop-streaming-2.6.0.jar -input wasb:///CSV/ -output
 wasb:///Output/reducer1.txt -file ./Mapper.exe -mapper Mapper.exe 
-file ./Reducer.exe -reducer Reducer.exe
```

I get the following error in my output file:

```
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 
'MathNet.Numerics, Version=3.11.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'
 or one of its dependencies.
File name: 'MathNet.Numerics, Version=3.11.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'
```

I've also tried to copy to MathNet.Numerics.dll to the cluster and include the file with a tag in the initial command:

```
hadoop jar ./hadoop-streaming-2.6.0.jar -input wasb:///CSV/ -output
 wasb:///Output/reducer1.txt -file ./Mapper.exe -mapper Mapper.exe 
-file ./Reducer.exe -reducer Reducer.exe -file ./MathNet.Numerics.dll
```

but had the same result.

Answer (score 0):

**On windows in VS 2014+**
-Right click on "references", in the solution explorer.
-Select: Manage NuGet Packages
Click Browse, then type in the library your trying to install, it should grab everything you need including dependencies.

**On Linux with Mono:**
-https://docs.nuget.org/contribute/setting-up-the-nuget-development-environment
-Scroll down to the Linux install instructions

I have not used NuGet on Mono, but I assume it should work exactly the same way. I would at least try it to see if you're simply missing a dependency somewhere, as it should auto-magically get them for you.

Comment: thanks for responding. That's how I downloaded the dll initially. I edited my question to reflect that

Comment: Then I would think there's either an unstated dependency somewhere that's been overlooked by someone, or an undocumented bug between the release and your distro. Perhaps try reverting to a slightly older release? Or send the dev team a message on IRC/Forums?